# Is asking for an MS Outlook add-in skeleton on-topic?

Tags: discussion

As far as I know, asking for code libraries is on topic. I believe that asking for frameworks is too.

Would the following be on topic, asking for a skeleton app? If not, could it be made on topic?

---

I am a professional embedded software developer. I have some self taught web skills, with PHP & AngularJs 1.x.

Now, I am trying to develop an MS Outlook web add-in. I want it to be an angular JS app, without using MS Visual Studio. I plan to add a button to the tool bar, and invoking it will start an Angular app which I have already coded & tested.

Sounds simple, huh? Just drop the existing app into a web add-in skeleton.

I have spent my evenings and weekends for several weeks now, following one tutorial after another, and am still getting nowhere.

What am I look for is:

- an MS Outlook web add-in (not using Visual Studio)
- for the message compose pane, ***not*** message read, which what most of the examples are for
- it should add a button to the message compose frame, which launches my app in a window beside the compose frame
- I would not object to a button on the main ribbon which launches compose, with my app in the side window, but that is not "must have"
- when the app launches, an `alert("Hello, world");` would be nice, preferably from the controller.  That's all that it needs to do; I will provide the rest

If I can have that, I know that I can slot my app into it.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't. Sits somewhere between a full addon and a library. Both types are permitted here. Buit let's see what the community says ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking for a piece of software that does X and Y and displays `Hello, world` after a specific action, and you add the requirement of the source code being available.

For me it is an addon request, and thus on-topic if the requirements are clear enough and not too broad.